# clearing ng-messages in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to working with ng-message.  I have an error message (form.$error below) showing up when I don't want it to, while a user is typing and changing their incorrect entry. how can I either a) use ng-focus properly or b) clear ng-messages in my controller when a user is typing? my attempt at a) using ng-focus is below but it isn't working. I also tried replacing ng-focus with ng-change but that still doesn't work. is it also possible to manually disable the error message from showing up in the controller by clearing ng-message?

my html. I attempt to set the form to valid when the user is typing.

```
 <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input ng-focus="setValid()"
    class="form-control" required  ng-blur="checkCodes()"
    ng-model="code1">
</div>
```

further down in my html I have this other div where the error shows up when I don't want it to, when the user is typing.

```
<div ng-if="codeError"
    ng-messages="form.$error">
    <p ng-show="code1 === code2"
    class="disabled-text long-error">Inputs can't be the same</p>
</div>
```

this is the main js in my controller:

```
 $scope.checkCodes = function() {


     if ($scope.code1 && $scope.code1 === $scope.code2) {

         $scope.showUniqueError = true;
         $scope.form.$setValidity("prop", false);
         $scope.showError2 = false;

     } else {
         $scope.showUniqueError = false;
         $scope.form.$setValidity("prop", true);

     }


 }
 //tried to use this in ng-focus but not working.
 $scope.setValid = function() {
        $scope.form.$setValidity("prop", true);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close you just had the wrong scope variable in your ng-if.

I also change the ng-blur attritbutes to ng-keyup. With ng-blur your error message would only be displayed if you click outside of the text box or another control gets focus.

In the live example you will see that if you type in the same value for each input box that your error will be displayed and if you change one of the input boxes to a different value then the error will be removed.

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/QyOZNR

test html:

```
     <div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController"><!--begin app container-->

<div class="col-xs-3">
    <input ng-focus="setValid()"
    class="form-control" required  ng-blur="checkCodes()"
    ng-model="code1">

  <input ng-focus="setValid()"
    class="form-control" required  ng-blur="checkCodes()"
    ng-model="code2">
</div>



<div ng-if="showUniqueError"
    ng-messages="form.$error">
    <p ng-show="code1 === code2"
    class="disabled-text long-error">Inputs can't be the same</p>
</div>


</div><!--end app container-->
```

Test Javascript(Unchanged other then adding module wrapper and closure):

```
     (function(){

  angular.module("test",[]).controller("testController",function($scope){

$scope.checkCodes = function() {


     if ($scope.code1 && $scope.code1 === $scope.code2) {

         $scope.showUniqueError = true;
         $scope.form.$setValidity("prop", false);
         $scope.showError2 = false;

     } else {
         $scope.showUniqueError = false;
         $scope.form.$setValidity("prop", true);

     }


 }
 //tried to use this in ng-focus but not working.
 $scope.setValid = function() {
        $scope.form.$setValidity("prop", true);

 }

  });//end controller
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using ng-message.

```
<form class="form-signin hide" id="gbLoginForm" method="POST" name="loginform" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">User Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="email" placeholder="User name/email" ng-model="user.email"  required autofocus>
              <span class="has-error" ng-show="loginform.email.$dirty && loginform.email.$error.required">
                <span class="help-block" ng-bind="getValue('EMPTYEMAIL')"></span>
              </span>
              <span class="has-error" ng-show="loginform.email.$dirty && !loginform.email.$error.required && loginform.email.$error.validemail">
                <span class="help-block" ng-bind="getValue('INVALIDEMAIL')"></span>
              </span>
            </div></form>
// email field is empty
        if(!$scope.user.email){
            $scope.loginform.email.$dirty = true;
            $scope.loginform.email.$setValidity('required', false);
            return false;
        }

  //invalid email
        if(!UtilityService.validateEmail($scope.user.email)) {
            $scope.loginform.email.$dirty = true;                
            $scope.loginform.email.$setValidity('validemail', false);
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use `ng-blur` or `ng-keyup`, because angular refresh your ngModel on change input.

To create the various checks can use directive [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko).

Live example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/0ona8usg/).

```html
<form name="ExampleForm">
  <label>Code 1</label>
  <input ng-model="code1" required/>
  <label>Code 2</label>
  <input ng-model="code2" required/>
  <div use-form-error="isSame" use-error-expression="code1 && code1==code2" ng-show="ExampleForm.$error.isSame">Inputs can't be the same</div>
</form>
```